# Ant plugin for Maven based on multiple build scripts: cannot find dependency

Tags: maven, ant, dependencies, maven-plugin

I am trying to create a custom ant plugin for Maven, based on multiple build scripts.  There is a note in the documentation about it: http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-ant-plugin-development.html (see "A Note on Multiple Build Scripts"), but I have not been able to make it work.

Here are the scripts:

```
<root>\src\main\scripts\A.build.xml
-----------------------------------
<project>
    <import file="C.build.xml"/>
    <target name="hello" depends="dependency">
        <echo>Hello, World</echo>
    </target>
</project>

<root>\src\main\scripts\A.mojos.xml
-----------------------------------
<pluginMetadata>
    <mojos>
        <mojo>
            <goal>hello</goal>
            <call>hello</call>
        </mojo>
    </mojos>
</pluginMetadata>

<root>\src\main\scripts\B.build.xml
-----------------------------------
<project>
    <target name="hello">
        <echo>Hello, World</echo>
    </target>
</project>

<root>\src\main\scripts\B.mojos.xml
-----------------------------------
<pluginMetadata>
    <mojos>
        <mojo>
            <goal>hello2</goal>
            <call>hello</call>
        </mojo>
    </mojos>
</pluginMetadata>

<root>\src\main\scripts\C.build.xml
-----------------------------------
<project>
    <target name="dependency">
        <echo>This is the dependency</echo>
    </target>
</project>

<root>\pom.xml
--------------
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.myproject.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <name>Hello Plugin</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-script-ant</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-plugin-tools-ant</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>hello</goalPrefix>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

At the root level, I run "mvn clean install", which is successful.

Then I run "mvn org.myproject.plugins:hello-plugin:hello2", which is also successful and produces the "Hello, World" output.

However, when running "mvn org.myproject.plugins:hello-plugin:hello", I get this:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Hello Plugin 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- hello-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:hello (default-cli) @ hello-plugin ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.531s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 08 12:52:25 PST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.myproject.plugins:hello-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:hello (default-cli) on project hello-plug
in: Failed to execute: Executing Ant script: A.build.xml [hello]: Failed to parse. Cannot find C.build.xml imported from
 C:\DOCUME~1\joanes\LOCALS~1\Temp\plexus-ant-component9129296102162378706.build.xml -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My question is how does one make this work?  By looking at the error, the script is executed in a temporary folder, hence it cannot find the imported C.build.xml.  Is there a way to change that?  What is the recommended way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Does it work standalone, i.e. if you run `ant -f A.build.xml hello`

Comment: Yes, I get the desired output ("This is a dependency" and "Hello, Wolrd").

Answer (score 0):

Try using: import file="${basedir}/src/main/scripts/C.build.xml".  It appears maven is re-writing or copying your script to a temp directory then executing it there.  It then tries to import C.build.xml from that directory because there's no other path information for C.build.xml.

Comment: Changing the import as suggested worked, but only if run from the base directory (<root> in the example above).

Comment: When run from another directory, let's say <root2>, I get:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.myproject.plugins:hello-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:hello (default-cli) on project test: Failed to execute: Executing Ant script: A.build.xml [hello]: Failed to parse. Cannot find <root2>/src/main/scripts/C.build.xml imported from C:\DOCUME~1\joanes\LOCALS~1\Temp\plexus-ant-component4838685001229146307.build.xml -> [Help 1]

Comment: Basically, ${basedir} gets resolved to the current directory :(

Comment: Yep.  I keep away from the antrun plugin for this and dependency resolution issues.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: I have filed a bug against Maven, it is MNG-5263.  If anybody has any workaround, that would be great!